# iOS multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS programming.

I have to implement a location search based on the third party map API, but I think I have messed up multiple view controllers.

Scenario:

I have a `mapviewController` for displaying the mapview. And I have a `searchController` for searchbar. There is a `resultviewController` property in `searchController` for display the search suggestions.

I have tried to add search VC as child VC to map VC, but once I click to the search bar it returns "Application tried to present modally an active controller".

So then I remove search VC from map VC & the search bar is not activated.

Therefore I want to ask how to handle these VCs, and avoid the case that map view covers the search bar and suggestion lists.

Thank you so much.

UPDATE:
I'm building a search bar in code. My aim is to build the following style in iOS.

[like this http://i1.tietuku.com/cd4efa23d97af75ft.jpg](http://i1.tietuku.com/cd4efa23d97af75ft.jpg)

I pushed the map `viewController` to the navigation controller from menu.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapviewController animated:YES];
```

And trying to add a searchController to it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

    _resultsTableController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    _resultsTableController.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    _resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; 
    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; 

    mapView = [[BMKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kHeight(100), kScreen_Width , kScreen_Height-kHeight(100))];

    [self addChildViewController:_searchController];
    [self.view addSubview: _searchController.view];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a litte more on your exact setup? Are you using storyboard or setting up the vcs in code? how are they linked? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @t0day I am not using storyboard. I have briefly updated the question, thank you

Comment: Why aren't you using storyboards? There's thousands of tutorials and youtube videos out there explaining how to set it up. It's not difficult, I suggest you rethink your project using them as creating VC's programmatically will leave you in a world of unnecessary pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for UISearchController you no need to add it as child view controller and and instant of using UITableViewController uses UITableView it make easy for you and 
here below is code that is .m file 
free to run that code and without uses storyboard.

@interface ViewController ()

{

```
UITableView *tableview;

UISearchController *searchcontroller;

NSMutableArray *array;}
```

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];


array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four", nil];


 tableview = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)/2)];


 [self.view addSubview:tableview];

tableview.dataSource = self;

tableview.delegate =self;

searchcontroller = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil]; // Create Reference of searchController

searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self;

searchcontroller.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

searchcontroller.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

searchcontroller.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

searchcontroller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;

[searchcontroller.searchBar sizeToFit];

tableview.tableHeaderView = searchcontroller.searchBar;


MKMapView *mapview = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(tableview.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)/2)];

[self.view addSubview:mapview];
```

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;

{

```
NSLog(@"update ");
```

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
// Default is 1 if not implemented

{

```
return 1;
```

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

```
return array.count;
```

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil)

{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should use only one view controller which has a map on it. Over the map you can simply add custom search view and on typing/ taping search you can show search results using `UITableview` with some dropping animation keeping some max frame fixed, And finally on taping any result remove this `UITableView` and show location of map. If time permits I will create a sample for you, cant give assurance but will try. Mean while you can also go through [Maps reference](https://developer.apple.com/maps/) may be helpful